# extracting specific data from a text file in python

Tags: python

If I have a text file containing:

```
 Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:11             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       12   dns.exe
  TCP    0.0.0.0:95             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       589  lsass.exe
  TCP    0.0.0.0:111            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       888  svchost.exe
  TCP    0.0.0.0:123            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       123  lsass.exe
  TCP    0.0.0.0:449            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2    System
```

Is there a way to extract ONLY the process ID names such as dns.exe, lsass.exe, etc..?

I tried using `split()` so I could get the info right after the string `LISTENING`. Then I took whats left (`12  dns.exe, 589  lsass.exe,` etc... ), and checked the length of each string. So if the `len()` of `12  dns.exe` was between 17 or 20 for example, I would get the substring of that string with specific numbers. I only took into account the length of the PID numbers(which can be anywhere between 1 to 4 digits) but then forgot that the length of each process name varies (there are hundreds). Is there a simpler way to do this or am I out of luck?

Comment: Are the number of spaces between columns the same in each instance? You might be able to use the csv module. [Docs here at python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: @cssko  Yes, they are always the same.

Comment: Can't you just take the last element of what `split` returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` should work just fine so long you ignore the header in your file

```
processes = []

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    # Loop through all lines, ignoring header.
    # Add last element to list (i.e. the process name)
    for l in lines[1:]:
        processes.append(l.split()[-1])

print processes
```

Result:

```
['dns.exe', 'lsass.exe', 'svchost.exe', 'lsass.exe', 'System']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas` DataFrames to do this without getting into the hassle of `split`:

```
parsed_file = pandas.read_csv("filename", header = 0)
```

will automatically read this into a DataFrame for you. You can then filter by those rows containing `dns.exe`, etc. You may need to define your own header

---

Here is a more general replacement for `read_csv` if you want more control. I've assumed your columns are all tab separated, but you can feel free to change the splitting character however you like:

```
with open('filename','r') as logs:
    logs.readline() # skip header so you can can define your own.
    columns = ["Proto","Local Address","Foreign Address","State","PID", "Process"]
    formatted_logs = pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(columns,line.split('\t'))) for line in logs])
```

Then you can just filter the rows by

```
formatted_logs = formatted_logs[formatted_logs['Process'].isin(['dns.exe','lsass.exe', ...])]
```

---

If you want *just* the process names, it is even simpler. Just do

```
processes = formatted_logs['Process'] # returns a Series object than can be iterated through
```

Comment: AFAIK, this format is **not** CSV. But I do not know if pandas CSV can process it...

Comment: You don't need CSV - the string split I've used will automatically take care of the column delimiter for you. Most log files are tab separated, hence the `\t`.

Comment: Pandas is a huge overkill for this job.

Comment: @MattDMo: Perhaps. Better to learn about a chainsaw now than use an axe until it is too late, in my opinion. Besides, much more fluidity and flexibility is offered should OP ever want to do anything more sophisticated - he can just reuse this code then.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `re.split`:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(" +")
l = rx.split("       12   dns.exe") #  => ['', '12', 'dns.exe']
pid = l[1]
```

it will split the string on a arbitrary number of spaces, and you take second element.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use simply split and treat the line step by step, one by one like this:

```
def getAllExecutables(textFile):
    execFiles = []
    with open(textFile) as f:
        fln = f.readline()
        while fln:
            pidname = str.strip(list(filter(None, fln.split(' ')))[-1]) #splitting the line, removing empty entry, stripping unnecessary chars, take last element
            if (pidname[-3:] == 'exe'): #check if the pidname ends with exe
                execFiles.append(pidname) #if it does, adds it
            fln = f.readline() #read the next line
    return  execFiles

exeFiles = getAllExecutables('file.txt')
print(exeFiles)
```

Some remarks on the code above:

1. Filter all the unnecessary empty element in the file line by `filter`
2. stripping all the unnecessary characters in the file (such as `\n`) by `str.strip`
3. Get the last element of the line after split using `l[-1]`
4. Check if the last 3 chars of that element is `exe`. If it is, adds it to the resulting list.

Results:

```
['dns.exe', 'lsass.exe', 'svchost.exe', 'lsass.exe']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(txtfile) as txt:
    lines = [line for line in txt]
process_names = [line.split()[-1] for line in lines[1:]]
```

This opens your input file and reads all the lines into a list. Next, the list is iterated over starting at the second element (because the first is the header row) and each line is `split()`. The last item in the resulting list is then added to `process_names`.